# How to solve a inductively defined set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, induction

I'm new to induction. Right now iIm working on a task which I'm not sure if I've solved it correctly.

Here is the task:

> *Give an inductive definition of the given language below:*
>
> $\{a^nb^n\mid n\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}\}\setminus\{\Lambda,aa,aabbb,aaabbb,\dots\}$

Here is my solution (I'm not sure if it's all correct):

> *The language can be defined inductive where the basis* $S$ *is* $\Lambda$
> $\in$ $S$ *and if* $t$ $\in$ $S$, *then* $a$t$b$ $\in$ $S$.

I would appreciate if someone could check if my solution is correct

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The first and fourth term in the subtracted set appear to be at odds with your inductive definition; unless $\setminus$ is not the set subtraction operator...

Comment: Your inductive definition gives you $\{a^nb^n:n\ge 0\}$. It’s not clear whether that’s what you actually want, however. If $$\{a^nb^n:n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}\}\setminus\{\Lambda,aa,aabbb,aaabbb,\ldots\}$$ is the set difference that it appears to be, then $\Lambda$ and $aaabbb$ are words in $S$ that should not be there. Unfortunately, there is no clear pattern to $\{\Lambda,aa,aabbb,aaabbb,\ldots\}$, so I can’t guess what the language is actually supposed to be.

Comment: what if you only had the > $\{a^nb^n\mid n\in\{0,1,2,\dots\}\} notation how would you solve that then?. I think the both notations are the same actually

Comment: @Dabbish: If you mean that $\{a^nb^n:n\ge 0\}$ is the same as $\{a^nb^n:n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}\}$, that’s obvious and irrelevant. If that’s the intended language, then your construction of $S$ is fine. But that is definitely **not** the same as $$\{a^nb^n:n\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}\}\setminus\{\Lambda,aa,aabbb,aaabbb,\ldots\}\;;$$ if that’s the intended language, then your $S$ is wrong, and since $$\{\Lambda,aa,aabbb,aaabbb,\ldots\}$$ is ambiguous, there’s no way to tell what is intended.